# @CrossOrigin Annotation works on one method of the Rest Controller , but doesn't apply for the second one

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-security, cors

Short description. I am trying to set up some rest endpoints in my back-end, and I call them from my Front-End.

I have two identical methods ( except that the path differs ), and one works with no problem, the newer one however, gets blocked by CORS policy on any browser after deploy ( AppEngine ). Ofcourse I tested locally but with Postman, which we all know it's not restricted by the CORS policy.

I leave the code below, but I cannot understand how one works, and other gets blocked.

package com.sjww.SecurityJobsWorldWide.controller;

```
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;
import com.sjww.SecurityJobsWorldWide.model.ContactModel;
import com.sjww.SecurityJobsWorldWide.model.NewsletterModel;
import com.sjww.SecurityJobsWorldWide.service.EmailService;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class EmailController {

    private final EmailService emailService;

    public EmailController(EmailService emailService) {
        this.emailService = emailService;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/sendContactMail", consumes = "application/json")
    public String sendMail(@RequestBody ContactModel contactModel) throws UnirestException {
        emailService.sendContactMessage(contactModel);
        return new JSONObject()
                .put("message", "SUCCESS!")
                .toString();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addOnRegistration", consumes = "application/json")
    public String addToNewsletterList(@RequestBody NewsletterModel newsletterModel) throws UnirestException {
        emailService.addListMember(newsletterModel.getEmail());
        return new JSONObject()
                .put("message", "Added to newsletter!")
                .toString();
    }
}
```

I tried to move the CrossOrigin annotation on each of methods, nothing. I tried to precisely specify which origin but same story applies. One works, the other doesn't .

So the sendEmail() is the old one. And the addToNewsletterList is the fresh one that doesn't work because of CORS.

`“No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource”` error

I have to mention that I don't have a class for WebMvc Configuration where I try to set some kind of rules. It's just this controller and a lot more with same annotation @CrossOrigin but just this method doesn't work .

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi OP, have you tried setting up `@CrossOrigin` above `@RestController`? Please see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors . Let me know if this works or not

Comment: Hello, I tried actually your versions , same story. Doesn't work sadly. I also tried what @Boug mentioned, but that doesn't work too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the "bug" .

The problem was that I was doing the http post request as follows :

```
this.httpClient.post<any>("SERVER_URL", "{email: " + result.user.email + "}").subscribe
```

Meaning that I forgot to add from front end this part :

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
};
```

and add it as a parameter as follows

```
this.httpClient.post<any>("SERVER_URL", "{email: " + result.user.email + "}", httpOptions).subscribe
```